# c++ memory leak and garbage memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I can see that if we allocate memory dynamically in c++, but do not manage it properly, we can have garbage memory, and we can essentially get memory leak, and it is clear why this happens. Because if for example, we have a pointer that points to a memory address, and we assign this pointer to another address space prior to freeing the current address then it is an issue. But what I don't understand, is that let's say we have a bad program that keeps adding garbage memory, but how come everything gets back to normal, when we close the program. If for example, we have a garbage memory that was introduced with a c++ program, so there is no more pointer pointing to that garbage memory, and how come after closing the program, all the garbage memory is freed? How does the program know how to clean the garbage memory before the program closes?

Answer (score 3):

There is no garbage memory, is not your program which allocates and frees memory. Its the underlying os. You are working on top of an os, using its services. Heap memory and the free store is only an abstraction which these services provide (Among other abstractions such files, "I'm the only process running in this unique CPU", etc)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows OS the operating system cleans up any memory that was allocated by a process. So, it basically throws away the space that was given to a process without caring about what it contained.

Comment: Addition @ OP: This means NOT that omitting delete´s is ok.